# How to let directories inherit the sticky bit and set different default ACLs for directories and files?

Tags: linux, acl

**First problem:** Is it possible to have the sticky bit on directories being inherited for newly created subdirectories?

**Second problem:** How can I set different default ACLs for directories and files, so that newly created directories will get the permission `rwxrws--t` (with the sticky bit `t` from the first problem) and newly created files will get `rw-r-----`?

Comment: It sounds as though you have a real problem that needs solving, and [this is not it](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: The "whole" problem is: I want a directory structure that belongs to the user "user" and to the group "group". It is not accessible by others. When user "bob" (also from group "group") creates a file inside there, it should belong to user "bob" and group "group" automatically and get the permission `rw-r-----`; when this user creates a directory, it should belong to the same owner and group as a file, but the permission should be `rwxrws--t`, so that any user can create other files in this directory, but only delete his/her own ones.

Comment: Okay. But what is this for?

Comment: Everybody should be able to create new files and folders in the directory structure, even in the subfolders owned by other users, but it should only be possible for a user to delete files he/she ownes. It should simply be a shared directory with these permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. Only group ownership can be inherited, by making the directory setgid.
2. You can't. You will need to run a separate process that detects creation of the objects and changes the ACLs appropriately.